# AngularJS 1.2.19 return values from nested $resource service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-resource

I'm fairly new to angularJS, but wrapping up a project and trying to clean up some code by moving a lot of business logic from my controller into a service call.

Currently my three factory service ($resource) calls all work correctly and the results are combined in the controller.  But I am not having luck moving all this logic into the service call and returning the combined object, an array.

Here is a much simplified version of my project:

```
var Myservices = angular.module('Myapp');

Myservices.factory('ResourceA', ['$resource',
function($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/resourcea');
}
]);

Myservices.factory('ResourceB', ['$resource',
function($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/resourceb');
}
]);

Myservices.factory('ResourceC', ['$resource',
function($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/resourcec');
}
]);


Myservices.factory('Results', ['ResourceA', 'ResourceB', 'ResourceC',
function (ResourceA, ResourceB, ResourceC) {

    var resourcea, resourceb, resourcec;
    var results = [];

    return {
        get: function() {
            ResourceB.query().$promise.then(function(data) {        // these calls all work
                resourceb = data;
            });
            ResourceC.query().$promise.then(function(data) {
                resourcec = data;
            });

            ResourceA.query().$promise.then(function(data) {
                resourcea = data;

            // other code here combines above resource calls and 
            // populates results[] array successfully ...
            //  
                return results;     // this is loaded correctly, but I can't return it
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

In debugging through this, I do indeed have an array of results in 'results'.

Now back in my controller I have the following code (simplified for your reading pleasure):

```
Myapp.controller('MyCtrl',['$scope', '$http', '$log','Results',
function($scope,$http,$log, Results){

// lot of initialization stuff here


// I don't know the correct call to get the 'results' array from my service back to my controller
// these all produce errors
Results.query().$promise.then(function(data){   //Object doesn't support property or method 'query'
    $log.info('Results: ' + data);
}
Results.query().then(function(data){            //Object doesn't support property or method 'query'
    $log.info('Results: ' + data);
}
Results.get().$promise.then(function(data){     //Unable to get property '$promise' of undefined or null reference
    $log.info('Results: ' + data);
}
Results.get().then(function(data){              //Unable to get property 'then' of undefined or null reference
    $log.info('Results: ' + data);
}
Results.get().success.then(function(data){      //Unable to get property 'success' of undefined or null reference
    $log.info('Results: ' + data);
}
}]);
```

As you can see, I have begun to resort to 'Trial and Error' with more of the latter than I desire.  I am obviously missing something, but feel I am close.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Cheers,
Dan

Comment: Since your service is already handling promises, try calling results without promise callback.

Results.get(function(data){ 
    $log.info('Results: ' + data);
}

Comment: Thanks Ara - I gave you a bump, as this resolved the errors I was getting and actually returned back to the controller.  Although the results set was empty due to other flaws in my code.  I'm gonna accept the below answer, as it got me close enough to understand and make things work.  I appreciate your help as well.

Comment: np, I was going to suggest taking a different approach mentioned below with $q.all but I didn't want to add more complexity until you had figured out the callback errors. G'luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear how you combine the results from `ResourceA.query()`, `ResourceB.query()` and `ResourceC.query()`, but the approach is probably incorrect, since the data are fetched asynchronously and you seem to be trying to combine them synchronously.
Furthermore, you can't call `Results.query()`, because there is no such method.

You need to combine the A, B, C results asynchronously.
This also means you can't return `results` from your `Results.get()` method. You need to return a promise that gets resolved once the data is fetched and combined.

You can combine multiple promises into one using **[`$q.all()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all)**.

E.g.:

```
Myservices.factory('Results', function ($q, ResourceA, ResourceB, ResourceC) {
    var results = [];

    return {
        get: function () {
            var dataA = ResourceA.query();
            var dataB = ResourceB.query();
            var dataC = ResourceC.query();

            var resultsPromise = $q.all({
                a: dataA.$promise,
                b: dataB.$promise,
                c: dataC.$promise
            }).then(function (data) {
                var results = [].concat(dataA).concat(dataB).concat(dataC);
                return results;
            }).catch(function (error) {/* Handle the error... */});

            return resultsPromise;
        }
    };
});
```

Then, you can use it in your controller like this:

```
Myapp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $log, Results) {
    ...
    Results.get().then(function (results) {
        $scope.results = results;
        $log.info(results);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks "ExpertSystem" - this got me close enough and really helped my understanding of $q and $promises.  I realize that generalizing my example made it difficult to understand.  The combination of results from the individual queries was a new array with most of dataA and then additional bits of dataB and dataC logically thrown in.

My final "results" array is actually an array of arrays.  The new array above, as well as dataB and dataC arrays.  I pushed these all onto results[] and I was good to go.  I split them back out once I returned to the controller.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: One issue I had with your answer, I receive an error with the .error portion of the resultsPromise above.  The error states "Object doesn't support property or method 'error' ".

I resolved this with:
        .then(function(data){
        // success logic
        }, function (error) {
           // handle the error
             $log.error = error;
        });

Comment: @djmarquette:Ooops ! I meant `.catch(...)` instead of `.error(...)` (`error` is specific to promises returned by `$http`). I updated my answer - thx for the heads-up. **Quick note**: Using `.catch()` has the added benefit that it will also catch errors in the success callback (while your approach won't). It is rare to have errors inside the success callback, but it is better to be on the safe side :)